# How can I find a closed form for the serie $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \exp(x)^n \exp(y)^{n^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I am trying to find a closed-form expression for the following sum:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \exp(x)^n  \exp(y)^{n^2}  \tag{1}
$$
This sum seems to be very related to the Jacobi theta function:
$$
\vartheta_4(z, \tau) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n \eta^n q^{n^2} 
$$
where $q = \exp(\pi i \tau)$ is the nome and $\eta = \exp(2 \pi i z)$.

However, first, it might be trivial but the range of the sums is different and I haven't been able to express $\vartheta_4(z, \tau)$ with a sum ranging from $0$ to $\infty$. Second, it seems that the Jacobi theta function is defined with $|q| < 1$ which might not be the case in my situation, is condition indispensable? when I compute (1) with $\mathrm{mpmath.nsum}$ with $|q| > 1$, it seems to work.

Any hints and suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Series diverges if $y > 0$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, with some tests on (1) with mpmath.nsum, it seems to converge.

Comment: Trying it with $x = 0$ and $y = 2$ in Mathematica, the partial sums diverge quite rapidly. As one would expect, given that the terms of the sum are unbounded. Are you sure you did your calculation right?

Comment: Interestingly, WolframAlpha does not give me any results. Indeed, for $x = 0$, it diverges. I have tried with x > 1 and y = 2 and it seems to converge. For $x=0$ and $y<2$ it seems to also converge.

Comment: [That partial sum plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%28-1%29%5EnExp%5B1.1%5D%5En+Exp%5B2.0%5D%5E%28n%5E2%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C10%7D%5D) sure doesn't look convergent.

Comment: It converges exactly when $y<0$ or ($y=0$ and $x<0$).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be right!