# What is the formula for an infinite geometric series when the common ratio changes by a fixed amount?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

So I looked at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4668151/how-can-i-find-a-closed-form-for-the-serie-sum-n-0-infty-1n-expxn) and thought, "Hmm, I might be able to use the infinite geometric series formula." Then, I realised that the common ratio would involve the counting variable, which I don't think is allowed. Then I thought, "There must be a formula for when the ratio changes by a fixed amount each time." So is there a formula for this? Does this involve harmonic means?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Very interesting question!

Comment: A house without a roof is still a house, and can be somewhat useful. A geometric series with non-constant common ratio is ***not*** a geometric series, and the knowledge of geometric series does not apply to it. Math is like that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin but the common ratio increases by a common ratio.

Comment: So what? Do you imply that it should somehow make this series a geometric progression, despite not matching the definition of a geometric progression? No.

Comment: If the common ratio is changing by a fixed *multiple* each time, we can probably derive a result. If it's changing as an arithmetic sequence, no dice. I'm guessing you're looking for the former? One would have to in order to seek an infinite sum.

Comment: Oh right, this is even something that's been studied, I just forgot the name. Prepare to go down a bit of a rabbit hole as you study [the generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function).

Comment: @EricSnyder yes, by a fixed multiple

Comment: @Bananatexteismarvellous In that case, yes, refer to my link on hypergeometric series. Um... good luck.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. Could you be more specific? May be add some example.